# Cannot install Ubuntu due to a "problem mounting the file" error

Tags: 12.10

I downloaded ubuntu 12.10 iso image; but when i click on it, I get a 'Sorry, there was a problem mounting file' error message.
The same thing happens after I downloaded the 12.4 LTS version too.
I am on Windows 8.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using wubi or trying to resize a partition, install to a new partition, etc.?

Comment: If you are trying to install Ubuntu on Windows, as an alternative  you can try DaemonTools to mount the cd image or download Wubi installer (this probably will download the cd image again).

Comment: To install Ubuntu, please follow the steps provided on the download page. Note, you don't have to click or mount ISOs to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I had no trouble mounting the ISO file on Windows 8 simply by double-clicking on the filename.  This automatically mounts the ISO file to a virtual DVD drive and assigns a drive letter.  Perhaps your ISO downloads are corrupted in some way.  I am assuming that mounting ISO files in this way is working for you on other ISO files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I presume you are trying to mount the file for a bootable USB. Understand that this is a *bootable ISO image* that you downloaded and therefore *Windows* might have problems mounting the file. I have [*7Zip*](http://www.7-zip.org/) (or you can even use *WINRAR*) which I used to 'Open Archive' and then used "Extract" to extract it to a folder. From there I wrote it to a USB.